# Android : How to add animated marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

Please can someone help me to add animated marker like this [one](http://plebeosaur.us/etc/map/) for android google maps V2

thank you.

Comment: Since there is no obvious "animated marker" there, perhaps you could explain more about what you mean by that term.

Comment: I want to add this type of marker (.gif marker) in the example

Comment: hi, me also facing same problem, if you got the sollution please share here the sollution. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you may get idea studying it......

TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
//new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)

```
animation.setDuration(2000);  // animation duration 
animation.setRepeatCount(100);  // animation repeat count (total repetition)
animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
//animation.setFillAfter(true);      

img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score -4):

please use below code to set marker from drawable

```
       BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_position_tennis_ball)


        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                 .title("Current Location")
                 .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
                 .icon(icon);

        mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: Please feel free to explain how this will achieve any sort of animated effect.

Comment: @CommonsWare why do you think this wouldnt work? I have not tried Prakash solution but theoritically you can link it to drawable xml which has a set of images displaying say every 200ms.. Wouldn't that animate the image?

Comment: @Snake: You are assuming that `BitmapDescriptor` is capable of dealing with animations, and I am assuming that it is not (if it were, they would have named it `DrawableDescriptor` instead of `BitmapDescriptor`). This is why I suggested to the answerer that an explanation is in order.

Comment: Oh good point. I guess I will try it and find which theory applies. Although your answer made me lose hope as I was looking for a way to animate markers

Comment: @CommonsWare. And you win! (I am not surprised by the way lol). I tried it and it was crashing with null pointer somehwere in google library. IT is really annoying that there is no way way you can animate Markers in an easier way. Unless offcourse I missing it